# Любила его(,) как сына

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, запятые, как, сравнительный-оборот

Это сравнительный оборот? Нужна ли здесь запятая?

Comment: Знает тот, кто уверен — мать ли она ему.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В Вашем предложении запятая перед как не ставится.

Запятая не нужна, если оборот с союзом как входит в состав сказуемого или тесно связан с ним по смыслу.

Вопрос № 294062:

http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA+%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BD%D0%B0